# How to send the multiple messages to AWS SQS queue as a batch in spring cloud aws?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I would like to send the multiple messages to SQS queue at a single call as batch in spring cloud.
I found amazonSqs.sendMessageBatch() method in aws java sdk.
Is there any alternative in spring cloud aws api to send messages as batch.